# Search bar in table view fails

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a problem with my search bar. Im trying to search in a table view with search bar, but when I am typing something it shows nothing, and after I deleted all I tried to search all the restaurants disappear.

This is the code I am using. Ill post only what necessary

```
extension HomeViewController: UISearchBarDelegate{
    //MARK: Search bar
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
      
        filteredData = []
        if searchText == "" {
        
            filteredData = datas
        }
        else {
       
            for restaurante in datas{
           
                if restaurante.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            {
           
                    filteredData.append(restaurante)
            }
            
        }
        }
        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { // Dispare tastatura cand apasam pe search
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
}
```

This is the variables :

```
struct Category {
    let title: String
    let photoKeyHome: String
}


  let datas: [Category] = []
  var filteredData: [Category]!
   
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        filteredData = datas
}
```

This is my table view. Maybe im doing something wrong here.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
        
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = homeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! homeTableViewCell
        let restaurant = filteredData[indexPath.row]
       
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(restaurant.photoKeyHome)
        
        
        
        cell.myLabel.text = restaurant.title
        cell.myImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
```

For the datas, im using Firestore and firebase storage.
This is how im getting data from the Firestore.

```
  func getDatabaseRecords() {
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
           //  Empty the array
          filteredData = []
            
            db.collection("HomeTableViewRestuarants").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let newEntry = Category(
                            title: data["title"] as! String,
                            photoKeyHome: data["photoKeyHome"] as! String
                          
                        )
                        
                            
                            
                            
                        self.filteredData
                            .append(newEntry)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY3rb.jpg)
[After tried to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8thV.png)

[after I deleted what I searched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3nn.png)

Comment: `datas` is defined as an empty array. Then, you set `filteredData` equal to that empty array. Unless there's more code that you're not showing, it's definitely going to be empty.

Comment: @jnpdx I updated how im getting data from the Firestore. maybe is there something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `datas` is never been set. In `getDatabaseRecords` replace

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.homeTableView.reloadData()
}
```

with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.datas = self.filteredData
   self.homeTableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

By the way your `textDidChange` method is very inefficient. Replace it with

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {        
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = datas
    } else {
        filteredData = datas.filter{ $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil  }
    }
    self.homeTableView.reloadData()
}
```